# Show div onClick with multiple divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick

I would like to call this function with onClick event in html as I'm not an expert I need some help.

Now I have this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".slidingDiv").hide();
    $(".show_hide").show();
    $('.show_hide').click(function(){
        $(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();
    });
});
</script>
```

HTML

```
<a href="#" class="show_hide">Map</a>
<div class="slidingDiv">';
<strong> Content </strong>
<a href="#" class="show_hide">hide</a>
```

How to trigger the above script with "onClick" event in HTMl?

Thanks

Comment: `onclick` in HTML? Do you mean a click anywhere in the body/page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="toggle-next-div">Click me</a>
<div class="slidingDiv">Content here</div>

<a href="#" class="toggle-next-div">Click me</a>
<div class="slidingDiv">Content here</div>
```

jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".slidingDiv").hide();
    $('.toggle-next-div').click(function(){
        $(this).next().slideToggle();
    });
});
</script>
```

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/CjsAN/

Answer (score 0):

You no need to attach it with **`onclick`** in HTML page because you're already using ***click event* handler** in JS Code.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.show_hide').click(function () {
        $(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();
    });
});
```

**PS:** Don't forget to add the **`jQuery`** library in HTML page.

See it in in [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/ueHMP/14/)

Comment: My problem is that I have multiple divs with the same class (php generated code) and if I click on any single link it shows all the DIVs with the same class. That's why I need a function to be triggered by onClick event in html.